# Android spinner layout... it's crazy?

Tags: android, layout, spinner

i've followed this tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html§
but instead of getting this:
http://developer.android.com/images/ui/spinner.png
i get this, the default!
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/spinner_widget_item_selected_listener_country_list.png
why?
it's a differen code, i can't understand why!
thanks!

Comment: What version of Android are you running your app on  and what version have you set in the manifest.xml :)?

Answer (score 0):

That's because your emulator/device seems to be running on pre-ICS. The theme used is different there, and that's why there's a visual change.

Try running on a post-ICS device/emulator and it will work well. (Or use ActionBarSherlock if you know how to work with libraries, and then set the application theme to "Theme.Sherlock.Light".

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself.
it was for the theme, i need to use holo but instead i had a simple android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
i run in 4.0.4
now because i don't want holo, i've added android:spinnerMode="dropdown" in my spinner, and it works great.